# $L^\infty$ bound of $x^m \psi_n(x)$ where $\psi_n$ is a Hermite function and $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ - extension from Cramer's inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, harmonic-analysis

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the Hermite function $\psi_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Schwartz function defined by
\begin{equation}
\psi_n(x):=(-1)^n(2^n n!\sqrt{\pi})^{-1/2} e^{x^2/2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}
\end{equation}
according to the Wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Differential-operator_representation

Moreover, it is written there that each Hermite function satisfies the $L^\infty$ bound
\begin{equation}
\lvert \psi_n(x) \rvert \leq \pi^{-1/4} \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
which is known as the Cramer's inequality.

Now, I am trying to find a bound of
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \lvert x^m \psi_n(x) \rvert
\end{equation}
for any given $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

More specifically, I am curious about the asymptotic behavior of this supremum as $n \to \infty$ while $m$ is fixed. Would it remain bounded or diverge?

I searched for references myself but cannot get an idea about resolving this issue. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: It seems like there should a reasonable bound for each $m$ and $n$, coming from the expansion $x^{m}\psi_{n}(x)=\sum_{j}c_{j}\psi_{n+m-j}(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$According to the 6th display in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Asymptotic_expansion), for any fixed $\ep>0$ we have
$$\psi_n(x)=(2/\pi)^{1/4}(\pi n)^{-1/4}(\sin t)^{-1/2}s_n(x)$$
if $n\to\infty$, $x=\sqrt{2n+1}\,\cos t$, and $t\in[\ep,\pi-\ep]$, and
$$s_n(x):=\sin\Big(\frac{3\pi}4+\frac{2n+1}4\,(\sin2t-2t)\Big)+O(1/n).$$

Fix now any $t\in(0,\pi/2)$ such that $\sin2t-2t$ is irrational, and let $x_n:=\sqrt{2n+1}\,\cos t$. Then $\limsup_n s_n(x_n)=1$ and hence
$$\limsup_n x_n^m\, s_n(x_n)=\infty$$
for each integer $m\ge1$.

So, for each integer $m\ge1$,
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^m\,\psi_n(x)|\text{ is unbounded in $n$}. 
\end{equation}

---

Using [Szegő, formula (8.22.14)](https://people.math.osu.edu/nevai.1/SZEGO/szego=szego1975=ops=OCR.pdf) (say with $t=0$), we see that, moreover, for each real $m>1/12$,
\begin{equation}
\lim_n\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x|^m\,|\psi_n(x)|=\infty. 
\end{equation}

Comment: I am always deeply grateful for your detailed answers.

Comment: @Isaac : I am glad to help.

Comment: Could you perhaps help me with the following post as well? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450936/if-k-g-n-converges-in-the-frechet-topology-of-smooth-functions-and-k-approx