# If $K *g_n$ converges in the Fréchet topology of smooth functions and $K$ approximates $\delta(x)$, is $g_n$ itself convergent? - revised

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let us consider the Fréchet space $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ of real-valued, periodic smooth functions.

That is, $f_n \to f$ in $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ if $f^{(m)}_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $f^{(m)}$ as $n \to \infty$ and for each $m \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Now, suppose that there exist two sequences $\{g_n\},\{K_m\}  \subset C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ such that

1. $K_m(x) \to \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-k)$ as $m \to \infty$ in the sense of distributions.
2. $\{ g_n * K_m \}$ is convergent in $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ as $n \to \infty$ for each fixed $m$. Here $(g_n * K_m)(x):=\int_0^1 g_n(x-y)K_m(y)dy$.

Then, I wonder if $g_n$ itself is convergent in $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ as well. Or at least, is there a convergent subsequence of $g_n$?

Edition : I am grateful for the counterexample provided by Iosif Pinelis. It certainly seems that I need further conditions. So, I assume that $g_n$ converges almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ to some $L^1$ function $g$. In this case, is $g$ in fact smooth and $g_n$ converges to $g$ in the Frechet topology defined above?

I may write a new post if this is too much of an addition.

Comment: It looks like the question is equivalent to one on the circle, where all distributions have Fourier expansions with polynomial-growth coefficients, and vice-versa. This might simplify things...?

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings: What exactly do you mean by $C^\infty([0,1],mathbb{R})$? Do all derivatives extend to a continuous function on the closed interval?

Comment: @paulgarrett yes, it is on the circle. How does the polynomial growth simplify things??

Comment: @Christian all derivatives are periodic as well as the original function. So, they are in fact smooth on the real line, just like trigonometric functions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: (1) cannot hold if taken at face value since the $K_m$ were introduced as functions on $[0,1]$. Are you referring to their periodic extensions here?

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes, in fact, I had the Jacobi-Theta function in mind for $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$No (assuming that your $C^\infty\big([0,1],\R\big)$ denotes the set of all smooth periodic functions of period $1$, endowed with the topology specified in your post).

E.g., let
\begin{equation}
    g_n(x):=\sin2\pi nx \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation*}
    K_m(x):=\frac m2\,\sum_{k\in\Z}\big(L(m(x-k)-1)+L(m(x-k)+1)\big),  
\end{equation*}
where $L$ is a smooth nonnegative function supported on $[-1,1]$ such that $\int_\R L=1$.

Here is the graph $\{(x,K_m(x))\colon-3.5<x<3.5\}$ for $m=20$ and $L(x)=ce^{-1/(1-x^2)}\,1(|x|<1)$, where $c:=1/\int_{-1}^1 dx\,e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$:

[image]

Then your condition 1 holds. Also, for
$$h_{n,m}:=g_n*K_m$$
we have
\begin{equation*}
    h_{n,m}(x)=\int_{x-1}^x dt\,K_m(x-t)g_n(t). 
\end{equation*}
Therefore and because the function $K_m$ and all its derivatives vanish on $\Z$, for all $j=0,1,\dots$ we have
\begin{equation*}
        h^{(j)}_{n,m}(x)=\sum_{k\in\Z}I_{n,m,k,j}(x)=\sum_{k=-1}^2I_{n,m,k,j}(x) \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
for $m\ge2$, where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    I_{n,m,k,j}(x):=\frac{m^j}2\int_{x-1}^x & dt\, \sin2\pi nt\, \\ 
    &\times\big(L^{(j)}(m(x-t-k)-1)+L^{(j)}(m(x-t-k)+1)\big), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
so that $I_{n,m,k,j}(x)=0$ if $k\in\Z\setminus\{-1,0,1,2\}$.
Writing now $dt\, \sin2\pi nt=-d\dfrac{\cos2\pi nt}{2\pi n}$ and integrating by parts, we get
\begin{equation*}
    |I_{n,m,k,j}(x)|\le C/n,
\end{equation*}
where $C$ is a positive real number not depending on $n$ or $x$. So, in view of \eqref{10}, $g_n*K_m=h_{n,m}$ converges to $0$ (as $n\to\infty$) in $C^\infty\big([0,1],\R\big)$. So, your condition 2 holds as well.

However, in view of \eqref{0}, $g_n$ does not converge in $C^\infty\big([0,1],\R\big)$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your amazing answer.. I in fact added further conditions that $g_n$ converges a.e. to some integrable function $g$. Then, perhaps the situation will change? Could you provide any insight?

Comment: @Isaac : The answer would still be no: Replace $g_n(x):=\sin2\pi nx$ by (say) $g_n(x):=\frac1n\,\sin2\pi nx$.

Comment: I see. At least, I can see that $g=0$ is smooth. I am more curious about regularity of $g$ than convergence to it. Perhaps, it may be possible that $g$ is necessarily smooth?

Comment: @Isaac : I am not sure what you mean by $g$ here.

Comment: $g$ is the $L^1$ function to which $g_n$ is assumed to converge a.e. on $[0,1]$. According to your new counterexample, $g=0$ due to presence of $1/n$ in $g_n$.

Comment: @Isaac : I think the answer would still be no, but this will probably require a separate question and a separate answer.

Comment: I made it into a separate question : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450994/k-g-n-converges-in-the-topology-of-smooth-functions-k-approximates-delta  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series version is a variant of @IosifPinelis' [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450946):

Let's grant ourselves that we're talking about functions on the circle, and that smooth functions are the same as Fourier series with rapidly decaying coefficients. Somewhat more subtly, distributions have Fourier expansions with moderate-growth (slower than some polynomial) coefficients, and the evaluation map is the obvious restriction-and-extension of Parseval's theorem….

Convolution is (conveniently?) converted to multiplication: $$(\sum_m a_me^{2\pi imx})*(\sum_n b_ne^{2\pi inx})\;=\; \sum_\ell a_\ell b_\ell e^{2\pi i\ell x}.
$$

In that context, perhaps even without using some of those facts, take $K_n(x)=\sum_{\lvert\ell\rvert\le n} 1\cdot e^{2\pi i\ell x}$ and $g_n(x)=e^{2\pi i(n+1)x}$, or maybe $n\cdot e^{2\pi i (n+1)x}$.
Since the Dirac comb (= periodic $\delta$) has Fourier expansion $\sum_n 1\cdot e^{2\pi inx}$ (convergent in the sense of distributions, and, in fact, in a Sobolev space…), $K_n\to \delta$. Since $K_n*g_n=0$ for all $n$, it converges even in the strongest possible sense to the smooth function $0$. On the other hand, the $g_n$'s are not a Cauchy sequence in the topology on smooth functions… and by tweaking the constant, they're not Cauchy in $L^2$, etc.

EDIT: but/and, yes, various hypotheses on the $g_n$ do allow some conclusions. One significant mechanism is the "basic" fact that separately-continuous bilinear functionals on pairs of Frechet spaces (and maybe LF... or other colimits) are auto-magically jointly continuous. Thus, if the $g_n$'s have a limit, e.g., in some Sobolev space, and $K_n$'s have a limit in a Sobolev space (where periodic $\delta$ lives), then $K_n*g_n$'s limit must be the same as $\lim K_n * \lim g_n$, etc. In the example I gave, of $g_n=e^{2\pi inx}$, while this is not Cauchy in $L^2$, it *is* Cauchy in any negative-index $L^2$ Sobolev space.