# $K *g_n$ converges in the topology of smooth functions, $K$ approximates $\delta(x)$ and $g_n$ is a.e convergent to $g$, then regularity of $g$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, schwartz-distributions

This question is continuation from [If $K *g_n$ converges in the Fréchet topology of smooth functions and $K$ approximates $\delta(x)$, is $g_n$ itself convergent? - revised](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450936/if-k-g-n-converges-in-the-fr%c3%a9chet-topology-of-smooth-functions-and-k-approx).

As before, let us consider the Fréchet space $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ of real-valued, periodic smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $1$.

That is, $f_n \to f$ in $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ if $f^{(m)}_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ (or $\mathbb{R}$) to $f^{(m)}$ as $n \to \infty$ and for each $m \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Now, suppose that there exist two sequences $\{g_n\},\{K_m\}  \subset C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ such that

1. $K_m(x) \to \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-k)$ as $m \to \infty$ in the sense of distributions.
2. $g_n \to g$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ for some $g \in L^1[0,1]$.
3. $\{ g_n * K_m \}$ is convergent in $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$ as $n \to \infty$ for each fixed $m$. Here $(g_n * K_m)(x):=\int_0^1 g_n(x-y)K_m(y)dy$.

The example of $g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sin(2\pi n x)$ together with $g=0$ provided in the above link shows that $g_n$ does NOT necessarily converge to $g$ in the Fréchet topology of $C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$.

However, I still wonder if we can guarantee some regularity of $g$ from the above 1,2,3 items. Hopefully, would be it possible that $g \in C^\infty\Bigl([0,1],\mathbb{R} \Bigr)$? Or at least would $g$ be a continuous periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $1$?

I deeply appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$The answer is still no.

E.g., let $g$ be the $1$-periodic function such that
\begin{equation*}
    g(x)=1(|x-1/2|<1/4) \text{ for }x\in[0,1]. 
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{equation*}
    g_n(x):=n\int_\R dy\,g(x-y)L(ny) \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    K_m(x):=\frac m2\,\sum_{k\in\Z}\big(L(m(x-k)-1)+L(m(x-k)+1)\big),  
\end{equation*}
where $L$ is a smooth nonnegative function supported on $[-1,1]$ such that $\int_\R L=1$.

Here is the graph $\{(x,K_m(x))\colon-3.5<x<3.5\}$ for $m=20$ and $L(x)=ce^{-1/(1-x^2)}\,1(|x|<1)$, where $c:=1/\int_{-1}^1 dx\,e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$:

[image]

Then your conditions 1 and 2 hold. In particular, $g_n$ is $1$-periodic, $0\le g_n\le1$ and $g_n\to g$ almost everywhere, so that $\|g_n-g\|_{L^1[0,1]}\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$).

Also, for
$$h_{n,m}:=g_n*K_m$$
we have
\begin{equation*}
    h_{n,m}(x)=\int_{x-1}^x dt\,K_m(x-t)g_n(t). 
\end{equation*}
Therefore and because the function $K_m$ and all its derivatives vanish on $\Z$, for all $j=0,1,\dots$ we have
\begin{equation*}
        h^{(j)}_{n,m}(x)=\sum_{k\in\Z}I_{n,m,k,j}(x)=\sum_{k=-1}^2I_{n,m,k,j}(x) \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
for $m\ge2$, where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    I_{n,m,k,j}(x):=\frac{m^j}2\int_{x-1}^x & dt\, g_n(t) \\ 
    &\times\big(L^{(j)}(m(x-t-k)-1)+L^{(j)}(m(x-t-k)+1)\big), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
so that $I_{n,m,k,j}(x)=0$ if $k\in\Z\setminus\{-1,0,1,2\}$.
Therefore and because (i) $g_n$ and $g$ are $1$-periodic, (ii) $\|g_n-g\|_{L^1[0,1]}\to0$, and (iii) $L^{(j)}$ is bounded, we see that
$I_{n,m,k,j}(x)\to I_{\infty,m,k,j}(x)$ (as $n\to\infty$) uniformly in $x$, where $I_{\infty,m,k,j}(x)$ is obtained from $I_{n,m,k,j}(x)$ by replacing $g_n$ by $g$.

So, in view of \eqref{10}, $g_n*K_m=h_{n,m}$ converges to $g*K_m$ (as $n\to\infty$) in $C^\infty\big([0,1],\R\big)$. So, your condition 3 holds as well.

However, $g$ is not even continuous. $\quad\Box$